# Insulating a Deep Rim Joist Cavity In Old Home

Tags: insulation, joists, old-house, basement-insulation

[image]

Recently bought this 1880's home and there are several very deep rim joist cavities.

There are three in total, 2 under the vestibule of the house, 1 running along the rear wall of the home (under one bedroom).

I've seen the foamular+spray foam recommendations for easy to reach rim joists, but I don't want the cold air circulating under the rooms these are under and could use some advice.

Comment: Whatever you use, crawling over all that rubble to install it won't be a lot of fun. I do _not_ envy you that job!

Comment: Are the joists sitting on rocks that are sitting on dirt?

Comment: Rocks on a support wall.

Comment: I've decided I'm going to get a 15' pole and just fill the entire cavity with insulation batt. It won't be great, but it will do something to stop the air getting under each room. Will seal off the end with foamular + spray foam to stop any remaining draft into the basement.